How to ignore upper letter when I search for widget in android studio
Sometimes searching for widgets in Android Studio can be tricky because the search might be case-sensitive. Wouldn't it be easier if you could find widgets regardless of capitalization? While there's no built-in setting for this, there is some setting edit in "analysis_options.yaml" I think example
